# Crear un prodecimiento almancenado con dos parametros y varias opciones por parametro

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

No quiero ser esa persona, pero necesito ayuda con esta asignación,

Hasta la fecha no habíamos percibido ni vistas así de complejas, el enunciado dice así:

Crear un procedimiento almacenado que reciba dos parámetro de entrada:

- @i_accion (‘I’ Insert,, ‘U’ Update, ‘D’ Delete, ‘C’ Consultar)
- @i_opcion (1 Cursor, 2 valor especifico)

Si *@i_accion* es *‘I’*, *‘U’*, *‘D’* o *‘C’* se debe realizar la respectiva acción SQL en la tabla `Authors`

En adicion:

- si *@i_accion* es *‘C’* y *@i_opcion* es *2* debe retornar un valor indicando **"Opción no es utilizada"**
- si *@i_accion* es *‘C’* y *@i_opcion* es *1* debe recorrer la tabla usando un **Cursor**.

Esta es la tabla `authors` por las dudas:

```
CREATE TABLE Authors (
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
Name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

He intentado darle un poco de estructura y por aquí voy:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE TWOPTIONS
@i_accion  varchar (1),
@i_opcion int,

AS

IF @i_opcion = 2

declare @value 


IF @i_accion = 'I' Insert into Authors values ()
IF @i_accion = 'U' Update Authors Set country = 
IF @i_accion = 'C' Select * from Authors 
IF @i_accion = 'D' delete from Authors where Name =
```

Genuinamente necesito ayuda en como organizar la data con todo lo que esta pidiendo el enunciado y no he podido encontrar ejemplos similares ni nada cerca de lo que esta pidiendo.

Answer (score 0):

EL enunciado, tiene muchos agujeros que no están nada claros.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TWOPTIONS
(
    @i_accion  varchar (1),
    @i_opcion int
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    IF @i_accion = 'I'
    BEGIN
        -- no hay parámetros para insertar..... 
        INSERT INTO Authors (id, Name, Country)
        VAlues (0,'de donde sacamos estos valores','para la inserción');
    END
    ELSE IF @i_accion = 'D'
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Authors 
        Where id = 0 ---que registro borramos no hay parámetros
    END
    ELSE IF @i_accion = 'u'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE A SET NAME = 'QUE VALORES PONEMOS PARA QUE COLUMNAS' 
            FROM Authors A
        Where id = 0 -- para que registros
    END
    ELSE iF (@i_accion = 'C' AND @i_opcion = 2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Opción no es utilizada';
        
    END
    ELSE IF (@i_accion = 'C' and @i_opcion = 1)
    BEGIN
        
        DECLARE @ID INT;
        DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(70);
        DECLARE @COUNTRY VARCHAR(100);
        
        DECLARE elCursor CURSOR
        FOR SELECT id, name, country FROM Authors;
        OPEN elCursor;
        FETCH Next From elCursor Into @id, @name, @country
        While (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
        Begin
            
            --- Recorrer el cursor, pero para que. Hay que devolver sus filas????
            FETCH Next From elCursor Into @id, @name, @country
        End
        Close elCursor;
        Deallocate elCursor;

    
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT 'Los datos pasados en los parámetros, se salen de lo solicitado';
    
    RETURN 0;

END;
```

¿De donde salen los valores para la Inserción?

¿De donde salen los valores para la Actualización, y sobre que registros se realiza?

¿Qué registros se borran y en que condiciones?

¿Para que recorrer un cursor, si no se indica que hacer con esa información?

¿Qué pasa si paso como parámetro una letra que no encaja, o un valor en la opción que no tiene implementación?

El TSQL puedes utilizar opciones If...Else If...Else para no tener que evaluar cada vez, si el parámetro `@i_acción` tiene un determinado valor, ya que si lo ha cumplido, el cometido del mismo ya ha terminado.

Las iteraciones con cursores, tienen muchas posibles soluciones, aunque no son del todo del agrado de los desarrolladores de SQL, puesto que van en contra de la matemática de conjuntos. Aunque alguna vez (las menos) haya que utilizarlos. Pero esta es una implementación simple. Lo importante es liberar recursos una vez finalizado el recorrido.

Espero te sirva en algo.